# Calendar date slicer must automatically select 'Request Start date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

below is my query. Kindly help.

I have a table visual in Power BI as below so when I select request id '1' all other visuals in that report page shows the the corresponding data. I have a slicer called 'Calendar date' where it shows date from 2019 to 2022 and user can select whatever dates they want.

My question is when user selects a request id from the below table visual, the Calendar date slicer must automatically select 'Request Start date. Is this possible?

```
Request id| Request Name| Request start date| Request End date    
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         |   A         |   DD/MM/2020      |  DD/MM/2021
2         |   B         |   DD/MM/2021      |  DD/MM/2022
3         |   C         |   DD/MM/2022      |  DD/MM/2023
4         |   D         |   DD/MM/2019      |  DD/MM/2019
5         |   E         |   DD/MM/2018      |  DD/MM/2018
```

Comment: [Creating a relative date slicer and filter in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range).   But maybe you should not store `DD/MM/2020` but use the real start date `01/01/2020`,

Comment: But using a relative date slicer won't resolve my issue. My query is when I select request id 1 in table then the calendar date slicer must automatically display the request start and end date.

Comment: then please [edit] your question and change " the Calendar date slicer must automatically __display__ 'Request Start date'" to " the Calendar date slicer must automatically __select__ 'Request Start date'"

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not possible in Power BI. Lets hope in future this will be available.